# The following packages have been kept back: PHP

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, php, php-fpm

I get this message after 22.04 upgrade on a Digital Ocean LAMPSTACK droplet:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  libapache2-mod-php7.4 php7.4-bz2 php7.4-cli php7.4-common php7.4-json php7.4-mbstring php7.4-opcache php7.4-readline php7.4-zip

9 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

`apt list --upgradable`:

```
libapache2-mod-php7.4/jammy 8.1.2-1ubuntu2 amd64 [upgradable from: 7.4.28-1+ubuntu21.10.1+deb.sury.org+1]
php7.4-bz2/jammy 7.4.29-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1.9 amd64 [upgradable from: 7.4.28-1+ubuntu21.10.1+deb.sury.org+1]
php7.4-cli/jammy 7.4.29-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1.9 amd64 [upgradable from: 7.4.28-1+ubuntu21.10.1+deb.sury.org+1]
php7.4-common/jammy 7.4.29-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1.9 amd64 [upgradable from: 7.4.28-1+ubuntu21.10.1+deb.sury.org+1]
php7.4-json/jammy 7.4.29-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1.9 amd64 [upgradable from: 7.4.28-1+ubuntu21.10.1+deb.sury.org+1]
php7.4-mbstring/jammy 7.4.29-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1.9 amd64 [upgradable from: 7.4.28-1+ubuntu21.10.1+deb.sury.org+1]
php7.4-opcache/jammy 7.4.29-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1.9 amd64 [upgradable from: 7.4.28-1+ubuntu21.10.1+deb.sury.org+1]
php7.4-readline/jammy 7.4.29-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1.9 amd64 [upgradable from: 7.4.28-1+ubuntu21.10.1+deb.sury.org+1]
php7.4-zip/jammy 7.4.29-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1.9 amd64 [upgradable from: 7.4.28-1+ubuntu21.10.1+deb.sury.org+1]
```

I have PHP-FPM.

`php -v`:

```
PHP 8.1.5 (cli) (built: Apr 21 2022 10:32:13) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.5, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v8.1.5, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

What to do?

Comment: Uninstall these packages and install 22.04 native (I think they will be php8.1 versions).

Comment: I have PHP-FPM because I have HTTP/2

Comment: There's php8.1-fpm package too.

Comment: 22.04 has **fully updated** packages to PHP 8.  You don't need to be using the deb.sury.org packages for PHP unless you *need* that older version.  This is why `php -v` shows 8.1 vs. 7.4.  You need to remove the Sury repository and use native, unless for some reason you can't (the hold back MIGHT be because they're for an older release or superseded or dependencies can't be resolved)

Comment: It's an old question, but I didn't get what you want to do. Do you need `php7.4` or you want to use `php8.1`?

Comment: Ondrej rep PHP vs Ubuntu inbuild PHP. I had a mix. Deleted Undrej PHP and installed Ubuntu's.