# How to safely replace Ondrej PHP with Ubunbu 22.04 original PHP repositories?

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, php

I have [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403558/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-php?noredirect=1#comment2437397_1403558) problem, and now I don't know how to safely replace Ondrej PHP with Ubuntu 22.04 original PHP repository?

I have PHP-FPM.

Comment: Do you need to keep downtime to a minimum? Or is it okay to bring the server offline for 15~20 minutes while libraries and repositories are switched around?

Comment: The server can be offline - no problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the server can be offline for a little bit, the most effective way to accomplish this goal will be to:

0. Stop Apache
1. [Uninstall PHP](https://askubuntu.com/a/187278/1222991)
2. [Remove the Ondrej PPA](https://askubuntu.com/a/310/1222991)

   <sup>**Note:** It may be prudent to visually confirm your `.list` files in `/etc/apt` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` to ensure that nothing is pointing to the Ondrej PPA location.</sup>
3. Re-Install PHP and the various additional packages that you require
4. Restart Apache